# UIscrollView, Autolayout and UIDynamicAnimator - Views flash

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uikit-dynamics, uidynamicanimator

I have a scrollView with two views in it. I want them to have gravity attached to them

```
    animator = UIDynamicAnimator(referenceView: scrollView)
    createViews()
    var gravity : UIGravityBehavior = UIGravityBehavior(items: [view])
    animator.addBehavior(gravity)
```

The views are created and added with autolayout.

```
        var view = UIView()
        scrollView.addSubview(view)
        view.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("|-(\(xPostion))-[view(50)]", options:NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics:nil, views:["view":view]))
        self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[view(50)]-(\(yPostion))-|", options:NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics:nil, views:["view":view]))
```

I can get the gravity to work just fine but when I scroll the views reset to the original position and then flash back to where they should be.

Below the two views are falling, when I pull on the scrollView you can see them flash back to there start position for a second. 
[image: what happens]

Edit: as far as i can tell this has to do with autolayout and the scrollview. If I use frames it was fine.

Comment: Have u got any solution .

Comment: @C_X no sorry, think I ran out of time in the end and had to do it with frames :(

Comment: Why not u use a container view inside scrollView and add animating object inside that... and  you can set height of container view to contentSize of scrollView